# Reference for some topics in Fourier Analysis

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

I am learning Fourier Analysis, and although things have been going well for a long time, soon they got extremely technical and I have started losing idea of why the proofs/theorems are important as I do not see many applications of these. So I would like to know good references for the following topics in Fourier analysis:

1. Paley Wiener theorems
2. Wiener Tauberian Theorem
3. Hilbert transform on $\mathbb R^n$

The first two have been discussed in Rudin. The proofs are long and very technical. Anyway, that should not be too much of a concern but I am not getting a feel for such theorems. Why are they important? What are their uses? Which references give decent exercises on these theorems?

Comment: Much of Wiener's work came out of working with circuits, radar, and general filtering and prediction problems. His work makes much more sense in that context. You might look through his collected works in your Library. I believe there is a 3-volume set, and they're assembled there in a an order that seems to make some sense.

Comment: What are their applications, anyway? I am looking for problems/exercises. Partly because I have them in the exam syllabus.

Comment: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Wiener-Hopf_equation . There are several good references listed.